# MySQL select and then insert or update if exists

Tags: mysql

I need to find multiple rows related to users and then insert into another table or update if record exists for current day.

I am doing this way

```
SELECT CASE WHEN
(
 SELECT 
 DISTINCT `userid`, 
 COUNT(DISTINCT `userip`,`userid`) AS `count`,  
 @date:=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
 FROM `tablename` 
 WHERE (`date` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())) GROUP BY `userid`
)
THEN
(
 UPDATE `tablename2` SET `count`=`count`,`userid`=`userid`,`date`=`date` WHERE `date` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())) 
)
ELSE
(
 INSERT INTO `tablename2` (`count`,`userid`,`date`) VALUES(`count`,`userid`,`date`);
)
END
```

But this is giving me syntax error near `UPDATE..`

How can I fix this?

Comment: you're using ticks `\`` where you shouldn't be using ticks *for one thing*.

Comment: `case` does not work over multiple queries. You can only use it in a single query itself

Comment: The keyword `TABLE` after `UPDATE` is not standard syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you want one row per user and date in `tablename2`.  If so, enforce this rule with a unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_tablename2(userid, date)
```

Then the database enforces it.

Your SQL is a mess, but I think I can see what you are trying to do. The basic idea is `INSERT . . . ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.  I think the following does what you want:

```
INSERT INTO `tablename2` (`count`, `userid`, `date`) 
    SELECT `userid`,  COUNT(DISTINCT `userip`, `userid`) AS `count`,  
           UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
    FROM `tablename` 
    WHERE `date` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
    GROUP BY `userid`
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count` = VALUES(`count`);
```

Comment: Will this insert query run select for every insert or just one time.

Comment: @TallboY . . . In such a query, the `SELECT` is run to produce all the rows to insert.  The `insert` then processes these rows.  If there are duplicates, then the `set` is done in place of the insert.

Comment: This is not working on update, it just inserts rows. I guess as there is no duplicate data as `date` and `count ` are always changing, and `userid` cannot be unique as there will be rows for same user on every day.

Comment: @TallboY . . . Be sure that `date` has no time component.  That can also prevent duplicates.